# How to mock Spark DataFrameReader using scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mocking

I want to unit test code that read DataFrame from RDBMS using `sparkSession.read.jdbc(...)`. But I did't find a way how to mock DataFrameReader to return dummy DataFrame for test.

Code example:

```
object ConfigurationLoader {

def readTable(tableName: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", s"$postgresUrl/$postgresDatabase")
      .option("dbtable", tableName)
      .option("user", postgresUsername)
      .option("password", postgresPassword)
      .option("driver", postgresDriver)
      .load()
  }

def loadUsingFilter(dummyFilter: String*)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    readTable(postgresFilesTableName)
      .where(col("column").isin(fileTypes: _*))
  }
}
```

And second problem - to mock scala object, looks like I need to use other approach to create such service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, unit tests are not meant to test database connections. This should be done in integration tests to check that all the parts work together. Unit tests are just meant to test **your** functional logic, and not spark's ability to read from a database.

This is why I would design your code slightly differently and do just that, without caring about the DB.

```scala
/** This, I don't test. I trust spark.read */
def readTable(tableName: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    spark.read
    .option(...)
    ...
    .load()
    // Nothing more
}

/** This I test, this is my logic. */
def transform(df : DataFrame, dummyFilter: String*): DataFrame = {
    df
      .where(col("column").isin(fileTypes: _*))
}
```

Then I use the code this way in production.

```scala
val source = readTable("...")
val result = transform(source, filter)
```

And now `transform`, that contains my logic, is easy to test. In case you wonder how to create dummy dataframes, one way I like is this:

```scala
val df = Seq((1, Some("a"), true), (2, Some("b"), false), 
      (3, None, true)).toDF("x", "y", "z")
// and the test
val result = transform(df, filter)
result should be ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You could participate in comments to the previous answer. We are talking about similar approach to yours.

Comment: I had missed the comments on the previous answer :) I was not completely satisfied with it at the time (now with the edits, I like it better) so I shared my vision in a separate answer. Is something still unclear? Do not hesitate if you have questions about testing.

Comment: I just wanted to cover everything, but looks like there is no way to properly test code only with unit tests.

Comment: Unit tests are not meant to test interactions between blocks. Apart from that, you can test almost anything. In your case, mocking the `DataFrameReader` would result in not testing it anyway. So what I propose is equivalent in terms in test coverage. Yet, if you want to test your ability to read data from postgres, nothing prevents you from setting up a test DB from which you could read data with the options you fancy...

Comment: Thank you, I have extracted logic related to reading into separate service and mocked this service in services where I use it. Looks good.

Comment: @Oli Can you please show, how can we mock the above example so that i can get good code coverage.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I understand what you want to mock.

Comment: @Oli `This, I don't test. I trust spark.read` I don't think it's about that, you would unit test it to check if the method was actually called with the right options and such. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does. But I would still not call the actual method. You could mock the dataframe reader or the spark session (easy without touching the code since it is a parameter) for instance and check that it is called the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test `sparkSession.read.jdbc(...)`, you can play with in-memory H2 database. I do it sometimes when I'm writing learning tests. You can find an example here: https://github.com/bartosz25/spark-scala-playground/blob/d3cad26ff236ae78884bdeb300f2e59a616dc479/src/test/scala/com/waitingforcode/sql/LoadingDataTest.scala Please note however that you may encounter some subtle differences with "real" RDBMS.

On the other side, you can better separate the concerns of the code and create the `DataFrame` differently, for instance with `toDF(...)` method. You can find an example here: https://github.com/bartosz25/spark-scala-playground/blob/77ea416d2493324ddd6f3f2be42122855596d238/src/test/scala/com/waitingforcode/sql/CorrelatedSubqueryTest.scala

Finally and IMO, if you have to mock `DataFrameReader`, it means that maybe there is something to do with the code separation. For instance, you can put all your filters inside a `Filters` object and test each filter separately. Same for mapping or aggregation functions. 2 years ago I wrote a blog post about testing Apache Spark - https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/testing-spark-applications/read It describes RDD API but the idea of separating concerns is the same.

---

Updated:

```scala
object Filters {
  def isInFileTypes(inputDataFrame: DataFrame, fileTypes: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    inputDataFrame.where(col("column").isin(fileTypes: _*))
  }
}

object ConfigurationLoader {

def readTable(tableName: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val input = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", s"$postgresUrl/$postgresDatabase")
      .option("dbtable", tableName)
      .option("user", postgresUsername)
      .option("password", postgresPassword)
      .option("driver", postgresDriver)
      .load()
    Filters.isInFileTypes(input, Seq("txt", "doc")
  }
```

And with that you can test your filtering logic whatever you want :) If you have more filters and want to test them, you can also combine them in a single method, pass any `DataFrame`you want and voilà :) 
You shouldn't test the `.load()` unless you have very good reasons to do so. It's Apache Spark internal logic, already tested.

---

Update, answer for:

> So, now I am able to test filters, but how to make sure that readTable really use proper filter(sorry for thoroughness, it is just question of full coverage). Probably you have some simple approach how to mock scala object(it is actually mu second problem). – dytyniak 14 mins ago

```scala
object MyApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val inputDataFrame = readTable(postgreSQLConnection)
    val outputDataFrame = ProcessingLogic.generateOutputDataFrame(inputDataFrame)  
  }
}

object ProcessingLogic {
  def generateOutputDataFrame(inputDataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    // Here you apply all needed filters, transformations & co
  }
}
```

As you can see, no need to mock an `object` here. It seems redundant but it's not because you can test every filter in isolation thanks to `Filters` object and all your processing logic combined thanks to `ProcessingLogic` object (name only for example). And you can create your `DataFrame` in any valid way. The drawback is you will need define a schema explicitly or use `case classes` since in your PostgreSQL source, Apache Spark will resolve the schema automatically (I explained this here: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/schema-projection/read).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't like an idea to use H2 as I have different storages and it is not universal approach. I am already using approach with separation but I still have some not covered code, that why I am asking how to mock reader.

Comment: Can you show your code ? Maybe there is something more to do with the separation ?

Comment: Updated post. Could you please also provide an advice for the second problem with object.

Comment: Answered. This separation should solve your both problems (or I didn't get the 2nd one correctly).

Comment: So, now I am able to test filters, but how to make sure that readTable really use proper filter(sorry for thoroughness, it is just question of full coverage). Probably you have some simple approach how to mock scala object(it is actually mu second problem).

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I will think how to split my code.

Answer (score 0):

**[Write UT for all DataFrameWriter, DataFrameReader, DataStreamReader, DataStreamWriter](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/spark-mocking-read-readstream-write-and-writestream-b6fe70761242)**

The sample test case using the above steps

1. Mock
2. Behavior
3. Assertion

Maven based dependencies

```
<groupId>org.scalatestplus</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-3-4_2.11</artifactId>
<version>3.2.3.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>


<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
<version>2.13.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

Let’s use an example of a spark class where the source is Hive and the sink is JDBC

```
class DummySource extends SparkPipeline {
  /**
   * Method to read the source and create a Dataframe
   *
   * @param sparkSession : SparkSession
   * @return : DataFrame
   */
  override def read(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    spark.read.table("Table_Name").filter("_2 > 1")
  }

  /**
   * Method to transform the dataframe
   *
   * @param df : DataFrame
   * @return : DataFrame
   */
  override def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = ???

  /**
   * Method to write/save the Dataframe to a target
   *
   * @param df : DataFrame
   *
   */
  override def write(df: DataFrame): Unit =
    df.write.jdbc("url", "targetTableName", new Properties())
}
```

Mocking Read

```
test("Spark read table") {
  val dummySource = new DummySource()
  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("mocking spark test")
    .getOrCreate()
  val testData = Seq(("one", 1), ("two", 2))
  val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(testData)
  df.show()
  val mockDataFrameReader = mock[DataFrameReader]
  val mockSpark = mock[SparkSession]
  when(mockSpark.read).thenReturn(mockDataFrameReader)
  when(mockDataFrameReader.table("Table_Name")).thenReturn(df)
  dummySource.read(mockSpark).count() should be(1)
}
```

Mocking Write

```
  test("Spark write") {
  val dummySource = new DummySource()
  val mockDf = mock[DataFrame]
  val mockDataFrameWriter = mock[DataFrameWriter[Row]]
  when(mockDf.write).thenReturn(mockDataFrameWriter)
  when(mockDataFrameWriter.mode(SaveMode.Append)).thenReturn(mockDataFrameWriter)
  doNothing().when(mockDataFrameWriter).jdbc("url", "targetTableName", new Properties())
  dummySource.write(df = mockDf)
}
```

[image]

Streaming code in ref

Ref : https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/spark-mocking-read-readstream-write-and-writestream-b6fe70761242

Comment: @dytyniak : Please go though the solution provided as it has helped me to write UT for all DataFrameWriter, DataFrameReader, DataStreamReader, DataStreamWriter

Comment: Hi @saurabh, how do we mock the dataframe with options? I tried in the above function. It's not working. did you try with options?